# Mysql Use aggregate function sum between two values

Tags: mysql

i have table number having entries

```
id  number
0    4000
1    2000
2    4000
3    5000
```

I need two find sum(number) between id's 0 and 2,I have heard of between operator but have no idea how to use it..

Comment: Google Google Google..

Comment: Write your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM yourTable WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple range you can use the `SUM()` aggregate function without `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM your_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 and 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description**:

> Here "group by" getting a sum for each id,
>
> "between for range of data in where clause
>
> Now , your query look like :

```
 SELECT id, SUM(number) FROM your_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 and 2 
    group by id;
```